# I keep getting "ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (11)" even though I am following an example problem

Tags: pandas, numpy, pickle, valueerror, pymoo

I am attempting to couple a pymoo optimization algorithm with a regression model. I found this fantastic example on [github](https://github.com/DataGasmic/EuroPython2023-Solving-MO_Constrained-Optimisation-with-Pymoo/blob/main/Pymoo.ipynb), and am attempting to follow the steps starting from In[16].
The example problem is probably using an outdated method of loading the pickle file (it wasn't working for me), so I'm using `Model= load_model('RegModel')` for my first model output and similarly`Model2=load_model('Reg2Model')` for my second output. I was able to follow the rest of the example up to In[69]. I'm also using two different pkl files to predict two different outcomes of my data, but when I use

```
result=pd.DataFrame(list(res.X))
result['Output1']=res.F
result['Output2']=Model2.predict(result)
```

I get the error in the question title, namely:`ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (11)`
(note that my length is 11 instead of the example's 5 because I'm using a different dataset. The methodology however is the same).

I tried not using the pd.DataFrame object and pass it as a numpy list but that also didn't work. At this point I'm stumped.
If I don't define Output 2 and simply define Output 1 alone
Output=res.F my code compiles, but it's obviously nonsensical.

Any help is appreciated, including the intuition behind In[69].
Appended is the full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 4
      1 result= pd.DataFrame(list(res.X))
      2 result
----> 4 result['Output1']= res.F
      5 result['Output2']=Reg2Model.predict(result)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3980, in DataFrame.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   3977     self._setitem_array([key], value)
   3978 else:
   3979     # set column
-> 3980     self._set_item(key, value)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4174, in DataFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   4164 def _set_item(self, key, value) -> None:
   4165     """
   4166     Add series to DataFrame in specified column.
   4167 
   (...)
   4172     ensure homogeneity.
   4173     """
-> 4174     value = self._sanitize_column(value)
   4176     if (
   4177         key in self.columns
   4178         and value.ndim == 1
   4179         and not is_extension_array_dtype(value)
   4180     ):
   4181         # broadcast across multiple columns if necessary
   4182         if not self.columns.is_unique or isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4915, in DataFrame._sanitize_column(self, value)
   4912     return _reindex_for_setitem(Series(value), self.index)
   4914 if is_list_like(value):
-> 4915     com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
   4916 return sanitize_array(value, self.index, copy=True, allow_2d=True)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py:571, in require_length_match(data, index)
    567 """
    568 Check the length of data matches the length of the index.
    569 """
    570 if len(data) != len(index):
--> 571     raise ValueError(
    572         "Length of values "
    573         f"({len(data)}) "
    574         "does not match length of index "
    575         f"({len(index)})"
    576     )

ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (11)
```

Comment: Hi Ali, welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you be able to add the relevant stuff from the Github link so that I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: also `result=pd.DataFrame(list(res.X))` etc. is ln 69

Comment: Hey @Mark! Thanks for the reply. And yes I meant In[69], I edited the original question. To reproduce the example, download "steel manufacturing.csv" and execute the code in "Modelling.ipnyb". Both files can be found in https://github.com/DataGasmic/EuroPython2023-Solving-MO_Constrained-Optimisation-with-Pymoo/tree/main
Keep in mind that the way he saved and loaded the pkl files is different to me, I saved using save_model(reg_model, 'RegModel') and loaded in the optimization code as  Model= load_model('RegModel').

Comment: The full error message, with traceback, might help.  If you don't provide enough debugging information, you will be depending on others to download and run the code, getting that info instead.

Comment: I added the full error message. Thanks for the handy tip hpaulj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're error is due to trying to add an array of length 1 to a dataframe which has a size of 11 (length of index is 11).

You should check how `res.X` and `res.F` look like. Are they consistent? And how does the dataframe look like? Is there something else in the dataframe?

Usually the amount of solutions in the solution space `res.F` should equal the amount of sets in the design space `res.X`.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The problem was that the genetic algorithm number of generations was too low, which somehow meant that the algorithm terminated before it could run to its entirety. Upon increasing it to 1000 instead of 100, it ran and this error disappeared. I have another error now, but this question has been solved.

Comment: Does that mean that `res.X` and `res.F` did not have the same size?

Comment: due to the fact that the algorithm terminated too early, yes. Otherwise res.X and res.F would have the same size

Comment: OK, in that case can you please accept my answer as solved.